# Invoke two different actions with same url in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

How to invoke two different Action methods based on the parameters supplied in Ajax request, but url should be same
ex :

```
        public ActionResult Method1(int a)
        {

            return Json(true);
        }

        public ActionResult Method2(int b, int c)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
```

sample URL : /Controller/Method but parameters supplied are different and so corresponding action method should get invoked

Comment: Use promises and wait for them both to be complete before doing anything else.

Comment: What do you mean _with same URL from AJAX calls_? You need 2 separate calls with different urls. eg `url: '@Url.Action("Method1", "YourController")'`, and `url: '@Url.Action("Method2", "YourController")',`

Comment: there is a scenario where you will have only one url say : /MyController/MethodName

Comment: And that will call `MethodName()` on `MyController`, so just do everything you want to do in that method and return the JSON you want.

Comment: OK little modification in above code say I have same Url in Ajax call but based on parameters supplied I'm calling Method1 or Method2. How do I achieve this.

Comment: Modified code :                                                public ActionResult Method1(int a)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Method 1 message";

            return Json(true);
        }

        public ActionResult Method2(int b, int c)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Method 2 message";

            return Json(true);
        }

Comment: Edit your question to include the revised code and delete the comment, and seriously what do you expect `ViewBag.Message - "..."` to do when you return `Json`?

Comment: @Mitesh. You have 2 different methods so you need different url's. What are you trying to achieve with this? If you know what the parameters are on the client, then just make the appropriate call based on those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript doing the ajax call you could do a check on a parameter and decide the url from this.
Something like (in pseudocode):

```
<script>
function YourAjaxkCall(param1, param2, param3){
  string url;
  if(param1 === someExpectedResult){
    url = '@Url.Action("Method1", "Controller")';
    data = param2;
  }
  if(param1 === someOtherExpectedResult){
    url = '@Url.Action("Method2", "Controller")';
    data = param2, param3 (Do proper converting to Json here)
  }
  'DoYourAjaxCall'
}

</script>
```